# java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null

Tags: java, android, json, nullpointerexception, android-volley

When I want to open an item in a listview that has been ticked. I receive the error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null

I use the volley libary for http requests. Here I make the request, And use another class for converting the json in an array.

```
public class Tips extends AppCompatActivity {

private SQLiteDatabase db;
public static final String INFORMATION_TIPS = "http://www.mydomainname/login/api.php?action=getTips";
public final String TIP = "tip";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tips);
    setTitle("Tips");
    populateListView();
    ListView tipsView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tipsView);
    tipsView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String tip = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    //userData data = new userData(db);
                    try {
                    tipsViewPost(tip);
                    Intent singleTipIntent = new Intent(Tips.this,singleTip.class);
                    startActivity(singleTipIntent);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Tips.this, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }
    );
}

private void populateListView()
{
    try {
        //lijst van items
        String[] tips = {"Hoofd", "knie"};

        //adapter maken
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tips);

        //list koppelen aan adapter
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tipsView);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(Tips.this, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void tipsViewPost(String tipView) {
    final String tip = tipView;
    try {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, INFORMATION_TIPS,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onResponse(String response) throws JSONException {
                        setTipsJson(response,tip);
                        return true;
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        try {
                            Toast.makeText(Tips.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return false;
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Tips.this, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(TIP, tip);
                return map;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(Tips.this, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

protected void setTipsJson(String json,String tip)
{
    try {
        parseJSON pj = new parseJSON(json);
        pj.parseTips(tip);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(Tips.this, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is my Json class where I receive it and put it in an array:

```
  public static String[] injuries;
  private JSONArray tipsJson = null;

      protected  void parseTips(String injurie) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        String value = "naam";
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            tipsJson = jsonObject.getJSONArray(injurie);

            injuries = new String[tipsJson.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < tipsJson.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo = tipsJson.getJSONObject(i);
                injuries[i] = jo.getString(value);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have now Idea why it throws that exception.

THIS IS MY ENTIRE ERROR:

> 10-29 22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio
>   E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService =
>   android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@283f51f8 10-29
>   22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio
>   E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService =
>   com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@bbfa6d1
>   10-29 22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio
>   E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService =
>   com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@bbfa6d1
>   10-29 22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio
>   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 10-29 22:35:09.547
>   7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 10-29 22:35:09.547
>   7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime: Process:
>   com.example.mydomain.fysio, PID: 7603 10-29 22:35:09.547
>   7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.mydomain.fysio/com.example.mydomain.fysio.singleTip}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null 10-29 22:35:09.547
>   7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3149)
>   10-29 22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
>   10-29 22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197) 10-29
>   22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
>   10-29 22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 10-29
>   22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 10-29 22:35:09.547
>   7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872) 10-29
>   22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 10-29 22:35:09.547
>   7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 10-29 22:35:09.547
>   7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>   10-29 22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 10-29
>   22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime: 
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null 10-29
>   22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.(Arrays.java:38) 10-29
>   22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155) 10-29 22:35:09.547
>   7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter.(ArrayAdapter.java:128) 10-29
>   22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   com.example.mydomain.fysio.singleTip.populateListView(singleTip.java:20)
>   10-29 22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.example.mydomain.fysio.singleTip.onCreate(singleTip.java:14) 10-29
>   22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550) 10-29
>   22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
>   10-29 22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
>   10-29 22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248) 
>   10-29 22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)  10-29
>   22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681) 
>   10-29 22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  10-29
>   22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)  10-29 22:35:09.547
>   7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)  10-29
>   22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  10-29 22:35:09.547
>   7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  10-29 22:35:09.547
>   7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
>   10-29 22:35:09.547 7603-7603/com.example.mydomain.fysio
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)  10-29
>   22:35:10.787 7603-10109/com.example.mydomain.fysio E/Volley: [11248]
>   BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for
>   http:mydomain/login/api.php?action=getTips

EDIT:

```
package com.example.mydomain.fysio;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class singleTip extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_tip);
        populateListView();
    }

    public void populateListView()
    {
        //adapter maken
```

//line20  ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter        ( //line20 (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,parseJSON.injuries);

```
        //list koppelen aan adapter
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.singleTip);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of `singleTip` class (`at com.example.mydomain.fysio.singleTip.populateListView(singleTip.java:20)` in the stacktrace) and point with some comment line 20

Comment: @RC I've done that! Please see my edit. Apparently my array is empty but why?

Comment: Pls move `Intent singleTipIntent = new Intent(Tips.this,singleTip.class);
                    startActivity(singleTipIntent);` into `onResponse` inside `public void tipsViewPost(String tipView)`

Comment: You are amazing! Now it works! Thankyou

Comment: But why does it matter?

Comment: What if I want to put this into a class I cant set the intent?